# Счетчик от 0 до N на JS + CSS

Tags: jquery, счетчики, css, javascript

Добрый день!

Стоит задача сделать счетчик как на странице [viboom](https://viboom.com/ru/), а именно "ПРОСМОТРЫ ВИДЕО". 
Пока что получилось так [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9E9C/11/).

Помогите, плиз, написать css, чтоб цифры перелистывались плавно, как в примере.

Comment: http://codepen.io/kindofone/pen/DkhAz

Answer (score 1):

в CSS используйте transition